# javascript with Mozilla/Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have a content Flow which grab the all images from server and displays,this content flow is able to display images on Chrome but not in Mozilla/Firefox.

I have this piece of code in js file.

```
            this.Opera=window.opera?true:false;
    this.IE=document.all&&!this.Opera?true:false;
    this.IE6=this.IE&&typeof (window.XMLHttpRequest)=="undefined"?true:false;
    this.IE8=this.IE&&typeof(document.querySelectorAll)!="undefined"?true:false;
    this.IE7=this.IE&&!this.IE6&&!this.IE8?true:false;
    this.WebKit=/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)?true:false,this.iPhone=/iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)?true:false;
    this.Chrome=/Chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent)?true:false;
    this.Mozilla= /Mozilla/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? true : false;
    this.Safari=/Safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&!this.Chrome?true:false;
```

Comment: Have you considered a JS library to provide browser abstraction? `jQuery` would be just an example.

Comment: The word "Mozilla" will very likely be to in the user agent string in non-Opera browsers...

Comment: Passerby please give a brief note.